# Dont render Search component with Router React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

With react-router-dom, I can't render my Search component, which I created, into the main Header component.

I think problem is in this line
<Route render={({ history }) => } />

but don't know what to do for two days now...

I'm trying to implement a search on the website but I'm stuck

Please help :D

Header.js

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

import Search from './Search';

import '../../App.css';

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <nav className='navbar row'>
        <div className='col-12 col-md-3'>
          <div className='navbar-brand'>
            <img src='/images/shopit_logo.png' alt='Site logo' />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className='col-12 col-md-6 mt-2 mt-md-0'>
          <Routes>
            <Route render={({ history }) => <Search history={history} />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>

        <div className='col-12 col-md-3 mt-4 mt-md-0 text-center'>
          <button className='btn' id='login_btn'>
            Login
          </button>

          <span id='cart' className='ml-3'>
            Cart
          </span>
          <span className='ml-1' id='cart_count'>
            2
          </span>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

//Search.js

```
mport React, { useState } from 'react';

const Search = ({ history }) => {
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('');

  const searchHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (keyword.trim()) {
      history.push(`/search/${keyword}`);
    } else {
      history.push('/');
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={searchHandler}>
      <div className='input-group'>
        <input
          type='text'
          id='search_field'
          className='form-control'
          placeholder='Enter Product Name ...'
          onChange={(e) => setKeyword(e.target.value)}
        />
        <div className='input-group-append'>
          <button id='search_btn' className='btn'>
            <i className='fa fa-search' aria-hidden='true'></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

//App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Header from './components/layout/Header';
import Footer from './components/layout/Footer';

import Home from './components/Home';
import ProductDetails from './components/product/ProductDetails';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className='App'>
        <Header />
        <div className='container container-fluid'>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<Home />} exact />
            <Route path='/search/:keyword' element={<Home />} />
            <Route path='/product/:id' element={<ProductDetails />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I think you are missing `<BrowserRouter>` provider.

Comment: Its not that :(

Comment: Could you please put it in a sandbox? https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

You are correct, cause of the issue is:

```
<Routes>
  <Route render={({ history }) => <Search history={history} />} />
</Routes>
```

In `react-router-dom` v6 the `Route` components no longer have `component`, or `render` or `children` function props. There also no longer exists the old route props. RRDv6 also doesn't expose out the `history` object and instead uses a `navigate` function.

## Solution

Since `Search` is a function component you can just import and use the `useNavigate` hook and replace the `history.push` with `navigate`.

Header.js

```
<div className='col-12 col-md-6 mt-2 mt-md-0'>
  <Search />
</div>
```

Search.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Search = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('');

  const searchHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (keyword.trim()) {
      navigate(`/search/${keyword}`);
    } else {
      navigate('/');
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={searchHandler}>
      ...
    </form>
  );
};
```